# What is the difference between AutoOpen() and Document_Open()?

Tags: vba, ms-word

They both fire when the document opens. When should you use one over the other?

Comment: AutoOpen is a special case macro that is run because [it's a convention](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/286310/description-of-behaviors-of-autoexec-and-autoopen-macros-in-word). `Document_Open` is a handler for the [`Document.Open` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.open).

Comment: AutoOPen is "old" - comes from WordBasic. It can be placed in any normal module. `Document_Open` Is an event and must be in the `ThisDocument` module. They trigger at different times (one before the other) which can be important in some circumstances. So mostly, except for the last point, it's a matter of preference.